# How can I add a sort of text box in SFML using keyboard input and sf::Text to display the string of text?

Tags: c++, string, input, keyboard, sfml

What I am trying to do is to check if text has been entered, then add that text to the end of a string. My current code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(){
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Window", 
sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);
sf::Font arial;
arial.loadFromFile("arial.ttf");
sf::Text t;
t.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
t.setFont(arial);
std::string s = "This is text that you type: ";
t.setString(s);

while(window.isOpen()){
    sf::Event event;

    while(window.pollEvent(event)){
        if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
            window.close();
        }
        if(event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered){
            s.append(std::to_string(event.key.code));
        }
    }
    t.setString(s);
    window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
    window.draw(t);
    window.display();
}
}
```

This works perfectly until I typed keys and all that was displayed was a series of numbers (the ASCII values of the keys). How would I make my program so that it appended a the key's char value to 
      `s`
instead of the ASCII value?

I hope I have provided enough information for you to help me. Any replies are appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-events.php#the-textentered-event) is your friend :-) In the event of a `TextEntered` event, `event.text` "contains the Unicode value of the entered character. You can either put it directly in a `sf::String`, or cast it to a `char` after making sure that it is in the ASCII range (0 - 127)."

There's no mention of the `event.key` member for the `TextEntered` event, which is intended for the `KeyPressed` event. The "ASCII values" you're seeing are probably garbage values due to the key member of the union being inactive and overwritten with other data. Also note that [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) only converts numbers to their *decimal* representation.

Here's some code that should work for you:

```
if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered){
    if (event.text.unicode < 128){
        s += static_cast<char>(event.text.unicode);
    } else {
        // Time to consider sf::String or some other unicode-capable string
    }
}
```